# Mostrar código JavaScript al presionar un botón

Tags: javascript

Buenos días tengo una duda, tengo un botón, pero lo que necesito es que cuando se presione ese botón me aparezca o active el siguiente código JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $zoho=$zoho || {};
$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {
  widgetcode : "323a03d4fc62756882e34a2c27bb028edaade236ab5390ed36ccb617947e9ec8",
  values : {},
  ready : function(){}
};
var d = document;
s = d.createElement("script");
s.type="text/javascript";
s.id="zsiqscript";
s.defer=true;
s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";
t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);
d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");
</script>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Gracias

Comment: Mete ese código dentro de una función javascript y procede a efectuar la llamada a esa función desde el propio event on click del botón, por favor.

Comment: Ok, deja lo hago

Comment: como que se refresca la pagina y como que se cicla y no carga la pagina

Answer (score 2):

Tenes tres maneras de hacerlo.

---

**Opción 1**

Usando HTML y `onclick`, para ello deberías definir la función y dentro de `onclick` llamarla como en el siguiente ejemplo

```js
function UnaFuncion()
{
  alert("Ejecute código JavaScript");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="UnaFuncion()">Un boton!</button>
```

---

**Opción 2**

En JavaScript: para ello, vas a tener que agregarle un `id` a tu botón para poder identificarlo fácilmente dentro de JavaScript

```js
//Uso getElementById para ubicar el boton por su Id y guardarlo
//en un objeto
var boton = document.getElementById('ejemplo');

//Asocio el evento onclick a la función.
boton.onclick = function(){ alert("Me ejecute!"); };
```

```html
<button id="ejemplo">Un botón!</button>
```

---

**Opción 3**

Por último, el uso de Listeners en JavaScript

```js
//Busco el boton por su id y lo almaceno en el objeto boton
var boton = document.getElementById('ejemplo');

//Agrego el eventListener click y lo asocio con miFuncion()
boton.addEventListener("click", miFuncion);

//Función de ejemplo que se ejecutará debido al eventListener
function miFuncion()
{
  alert("Me ejecute!");
}
```

```html
<button id="ejemplo">Un botón!</button>
```

Comment: metí el código en una función, pero cuando mando llamar esa funciona con el código JavaScript se refresca la pagina y se cicla.

Comment: y no carga la pagina, se cicla.

Comment: que queres decir con se cicla?

Comment: se refresca ya pagina y no carga, la rueda de carga del navegador sigue girando y no se muestra la pagina.